# Dummy email address implementation in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, email

Dummy email addresses such as aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd@reply.linkedin.com are used in matching services such as linkedin to allow communication by email without knowing the email address of the recipient.

I would like to know if there is a site that introduces how to implement such a dummy address function in Laravel.

We are assuming that we need to deploy a database in our web service that maintains a mapping list of legitimate - dummy addresses, exposes only the dummy addresses to the outside world, and relays the mail on some SMTP server.

Comment: Well they are using pipe services, when an email recevied, they pass it to pipe and and then match it with the data and that's it. And `aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd`@reply.linkedin.com that part of the email is there format or may be some sort of encoding or may be possible they store it their db against their user.

You can set `from` to what ever you want. [Laravel Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail)

Comment: Don’t think of them as “dummy”. If you can send SMTP messages to them then they are 100% valid email addresses that _forward_ (or if internal, could be an alias). This is just a simple lookup then, however it does imply that there’s an SMTP server/MTA capable of handling the connection in the first place

Answer (score 0):

For a domain, there can be a **default email address**.  If an email account does not exist then any emails for that address are sent to the default address.  That's how my domains are set up.

In this case there is a default address for the domain **reply.linkedin.com**.  The receiver code here then interprets the information in teh email to figure out where to pass it.

No function in Laravel is required for this feature to work.  What is required is the default email address and some code attached to the receiver of that email.

This code can be implemented in many ways.  Here are two

1. Have your code running, interrogating the mail server using **pop** or **imap** to fetch any emails every few seconds.
2. Have an **email client** setup to save the emails in a folder.  And have your code running, just looking for files in this **folder**.  You can have a OS event to inform the code when a new file arrives.